# C#: Есть ли способ написать Comparer в общем виде?

Tags: c#, generics

Для того, чтобы у списка IList вызывать метод Sort со своим способом сравнения, иногда приходится писать свой собственный Comparer, и подсовывать его в качестве аргумента методу Sort: `myList.Sort(MyComparer);`

В то же время я задумался: а нельзя ли написать Comparer в таком виде:

```
    public static int MyTestComp<T>(T a, T b) {
         return a < b ? 1 : -1;
    }
```

но получил ошибку

```
    Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

Логически я понимаю, что компилятор прав: кто знает, что за тип я подсуну! Но, с другой стороны, если тип реализует IComparable - то, вроде бы, такой метод написать в общем виде можно было бы.

А вот вопрос: а есть ли способ это сделать? То есть, написать такой Generic, в котором я "зуб даю!" что тип Т реализует интерфейс IComparable?

Спасибо заранее за советы!

Comment: `public static int MyTestComp<T>(T a, T b) where T:IComparable => a.CompareTo(b);` ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: @tym32167 - Круто! по моему, это самый быстрый ответ на вопрос в моей практике использования ru.SO! Спасибо  большое! Может, оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете явно указать компилятору, что обобщенный тип наследуется или реализует тот или иной интерфейс или является классом / структурой.

Пример

```
public static int MyTestComp<T>(T a, T b) where T:IComparable => a.CompareTo(b);
```

Больше информации в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).